# Charset no PHP com MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codificação-de-caracteres

seguinte:
O header da minha página está configurado assim:

```
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Configuro a conexão com o MySQL assim:

```
mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');
```

No meu banco MySQL a é configurado com InnoDB e a colação é "utf8_general_ci" com charset UTF8.
O único problema que está me tirando o sono é tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em VB-6 que quando salvo um nome em maiúsculo com acento, ex: JOÃO, salva normal, mas se uso a aplicação web (PHP/MySQL) ele salva assim: JOãO.
Alguém sabe o que pode ser, e como posso resolver este pequeníssimo detalhe?!
Veja a imagem:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor? "Quando usa a aplicação web"?  Poderia colocar o trecho do código php que faz esse Insert?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido!
Antes do meu insert eu pego o `$_POST['ap-nome']` e o coloco como uppercase com a função `strtoupper()` do PHP. Na documentação fala que os caracteres do alfabeto é determinado pelo local atual. Na mesma página tem outra sugestão de função do próprio PHP chamada `mb_strtoupper()`, com ela é possível configurar o charset. Ficou assim:

```
$apNome = mb_strtoupper($_POST['ap-nome'],'UTF-8');
```

Testado, aprovado e funcional.